# In what book does the story of "He who dwells in darkness" from Doctor Strange 1974 continue?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification

In what book does the story of "He who dwells in darkness" from [*Doctor Strange* 1974 #30](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/20110/doctor_strange_1974_30) continue? It appears as though [*Doctor Strange* 1974 #31](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/20111/doctor_strange_1974_31) is not the continuation.

Comment: The Dweller-in-Darkness shows up in issue #32; https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Dweller-in-Darkness_(Earth-616)/Appearances

Comment: Does it need to continue? It seems like it ends on a very generic baddy comment of "I will get you next time!"

Comment: Also the story in #30 is titled "A Gathering of Fear!", sure you've got the right issue? Unless you just mean the character "Dweller-in-Darkness", in which case Valorum's link contains all the information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The continuation to that story is found in the *subsequent* issue, Doctor Strange 1974 #32, in [*The Dream Weaver!*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange_Vol_2_32)**

[image]

It wasn't uncommon then (or now, for that matter) for stories to skip an issue or two if the art hadn't been completed or needed revision. You'll find another jump in issue #34, picking up again in #35, then completing in #36 and #37.

There's a [fairly comprehensive list of appearances](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Dweller-in-Darkness_(Earth-616)/Appearances) for the character '*Dweller-in-Darkness*' on the Marvel fandom website.